# my registration form captcha failed to stop when wrong captcha submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

it is php register.php page

```
<?php require_once 'config.php'; ?>
<?php 
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        try {
            $user_obj = new Cl_User();
            $data = $user_obj->registration( $_POST );
            if($data)$success = USER_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Registration Form</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <?php require_once 'templates/header_content.php';?><br/>
      <?php require_once 'templates/left_content.php';?>

    <div class="col-sm-6 center-content" >
        <div class="login-form">
            <?php require_once 'templates/message.php';?>

            <div class="form-header">
                <i class="fa fa-user">   Register</i>

            </div>

            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form-register" role="form" id="register-form">
                <div>
                    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User name"> 
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" > 
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"> 
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password"> 
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select class="form-control">
    <option value="Select">Select Country</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="AT">Austria</option>
    <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
    <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
    <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
    <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
    <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
    <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
    <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
    <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
    <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="TD">Chad</option>
    <option value="CL">Chile</option>
    <option value="CN">China</option>
    <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
    <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
    <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
    <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
    <option value="CG">Congo</option>
    <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
    <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
    <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
    <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
    <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
    <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
    <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
    <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
    <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
    <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
    <option value="FI">Finland</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
    <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
    <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
    <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="GR">Greece</option>
    <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
    <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
    <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="GU">Guam</option>
    <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
    <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
    <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
    <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
    <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
    <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
    <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
    <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
    <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
    <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
    <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
    <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
    <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
    <option value="IL">Israel</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
    <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
    <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
    <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
    <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
    <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
    <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
    <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
    <option value="LY">Libya</option>
    <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="MO">Macao</option>
    <option value="MK">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
    <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
    <option value="ML">Mali</option>
    <option value="MT">Malta</option>
    <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
    <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
    <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
    <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
    <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
    <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
    <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
    <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
    <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
    <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
    <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
    <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="NE">Niger</option>
    <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="NU">Niue</option>
    <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="NO">Norway</option>
    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
    <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="PW">Palau</option>
    <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
    <option value="PA">Panama</option>
    <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="PE">Peru</option>
    <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
    <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
    <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
    <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
    <option value="RO">Romania</option>
    <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
    <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
    <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
    <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
    <option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
    <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
    <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
    <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
    <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
    <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
    <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
    <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
    <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
    <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
    <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
    <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
    <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
    <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
    <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
    <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
    <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
    <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
    <option value="TG">Togo</option>
    <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
    <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
    <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
    <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
    <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
    <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
    <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
    <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
    <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
    <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
    <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
    <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>


                <div>
                <td id="imgparent">
<div id="imgdiv">
<img id="img" src="captcha.php">
</div>
<img id="reload" src="images/reload.png">

<input id="captcha1" name="captcha" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter captcha">
</td>
</tr>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div> 
                <button class="btn btn-block bt-login" id="button" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

                <h4 class="text-center login-txt-center">Alternatively, you can log in using:</h4>

                <a class="btn btn-default facebook_rnd" href="login.php?type=facebook"> <i class="fa fa-facebook modal-icons-rnd"></i> </a>  
                <a class="btn btn-default google_rnd" href="login.php?type=google"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus modal-icons-rnd"></i> </a>  

            </form>
            <div class="form-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        <a href="forget_password.php"> Forgot password? </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                        <a href="user_login.php"> Sign In </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
         <?php require_once 'templates/right_content.php';?>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->

        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/register.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my register.js with out captcha

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#register-form").validate({
        submitHandler : function(e) {
            $(form).submit();
        },
        rules : {
            name : {
                required : true
            },
            email : {
                required : true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "check-email.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        email: function() {
                            return $( "#email" ).val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            password : {
                required : true
            },
            confirm_password : {
                required : true,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        },
        messages : {
            name : {
                required : "Please enter name"
            },
            email : {
                required : "Please enter email",
                remote : "Email already exists"
            },

            password : {
                required : "Please enter password"
            },
            confirm_password : {
                required : "Please enter confirm password",
                equalTo: "Password and confirm password doesn't match"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            $(element).closest('div').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight : function(element) {
            $(element).closest('div').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
             $(element).closest('div').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
             $(element).closest('div').find('.help-block').html('');
        }
    });


});
```

only captcha js file script.js

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {
// Change CAPTCHA on each click or on refreshing page.
$("#reload").click(function() {
$("#img").remove();
$('<img id="img" src="captcha.php" />').appendTo("#imgdiv");
});
// Validation Function
$('#button').click(function() {

var captcha = $("#captcha1").val();
if ( captcha == '') {

} else {
// Validating CAPTCHA with user input text.
var dataString = 'captcha=' + captcha;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "verify.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(html) {
alert(html);
if(html='Wrong TEXT Entered'){
    preventDefault();}else{
    }
}
});
}
});
});
```

and fanally varify.php for captcha

```
<?php
//CAPTCHA Matching code
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["code"] == $_POST["captcha"]) {
echo "Form Submitted successfully....!";

} else {
die("Wrong TEXT Entered");

}
?>
```

here all filed validations are done fine with out captcha , when i entered wrong capcha also it submitting form
why ??

help me

Answer (score -1):

You need not to use ajax for verifying captcha.because session value would not get on verify.php.You have to check captcha value on submitting form.